# What is the optimal data structure to store large amount of data with low time/space complexity?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I have a question. Given is a text file containing more than 1000^2 key-value information. Each line contains coordinates and different information belongs to each set of coordinates. The data from the text file will be used a lot during local search. However, I wonder what is useful for storing this data. Ideally you want to be able to look up the data quickly, but on the other hand it takes a lot of memory to place it all in a dictionary. Or is leaving it in the file also an option?

In any case, I'm looking for the optimal way so that I can do as many iterations as possible in my local search. I'd love to hear what you think about this!

Thanks in advance for your time and help!